# Correct interpretation of random slope variance in linear mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

This question is about the correct interpretation of the results obtained from a linear mixed effects model.

Lets imagine I have a simple dataset with three columns: One grouping variable for subjects, one continuous predictor variable x and one continuous response variable y. I have 20 subjects and about 30 values for x & y per subject. In a first step, I did what my field does: I fit a simple linear regression model to the entire dataset (subjects pooled together) and found that there is a significant linear relationship between the predictor x and the response y.

**Next I wanted to check, whether this linear relationship in the pooled data is the result of a few subjects with a strong relationship or alternatively all subjects have a similar linear relationship between x & y**. In an attempt to answer this question, I fit a linear mixed effects model to my data. I included the predictor variable x as a fixed effect and included uncorrelated random intercepts and slopes for subjects. I used the lme4::lmer() function. The formula that I specified looks like this: 'y ~ x + (1+x||subjectid)'.
I compared the AIC of the simple linear regression to the AIC of the mixed effects model and obtained a smaller value for the mixed effects model. I used a likelihood ratio test and found that the random effects are significant.
Next, I looked at the coefficient of the fixed effect for x, which was, lets say, 50 y_unit/x_unit. The standard deviation for the random slopes was 5 y_unit/x_unit.

Interpretation: Taken together, I would conclude that the random effects structure leads to a significantly better fit of my data as compared to a model with only the fixed effect. More importantly, I would state that the mixed effects model predicts that **~95% of subjects have a slope between 40 and 60 y_unit/x_unit (fixed effect coefficient +/- 2 x std of the random slopes). I would conclude that the model suggests that a positive linear relationship is present in the vast majority of subjects, while the exact slopes of this relationship vary slightly.**

My question is: Are these interpretations correct?
Since these would be strong conclusions, I want to make sure that this is not nonsense. Maybe there is a better way to adress this. Also, I would appreciate help with the correct wording.